# Facebook Like button is not refreshing dynamically

Tags: facebook, wordpress, button, facebook-like

I've implemented the Facebook Like button on a WordPress blog and it is posting recommended links to Facebook.

However, it's not refreshing dynamically. I must refresh the browser and reload the site to see the updated Like count. Otherwise, when I press the button, it just grays out.

Here's the code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=450&amp;action=recommend&amp;font=verdana&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

And the site:
http://bit.ly/eYGXbo

I'd appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Have you tried the XFBML version?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>
```

to just

```
<?php echo $permalink; ?>
```